# Excel Ribbon dropBox does not refresh the list when I delete items

Tags: excel, vba, ribbon

I have a Ribbon dropBox with a list of sheets for the end user work. The list is in column “A” on the Data sheet, and the dropBox makes the sheet we select visible or hides it when we select another. If we select the first element (empty), it hides all.

One of the actions that the user can do is to delete the sheets, but in an orderly manner, and for this I have created a sheet editing form (UserForm1) with a list to select them (ComboBox1) and a button to delete them (CommandButton1). The form is necessary as there are more actions besides deleting.

Everything works fine except if the sheet I delete is currently selected in the Ribbon dropBox. The sheet remains selected even if it is no longer in the dropBox. If we display the list we see that it is gone. If we activate another tab of the Ribbon and return it refreshes and disappears.

Any idea how to get it refreshes well?

[This is an image of what happens:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGc1p.jpg)

To get the code to make it work properly, you must have a sheet called “Data” with a list of sheet names from the “A2” range, for example Sheets1, Sheets2, Sheets3, Sheets4 and Sheets5. The sheets must exist to be deleted later, if they don't exist we will have an error.

Also Sheets (“Data”). Range (“B1”) = 1 so that our Ribbon is active when opening the book.

Also create a form with (see the image above):

- 1 Userform (Name: UserForm1)
- 1 ComboBox (Name: ComboBox1)
- 1 CommandButton (Name: CommandButton1)

Paste this code in it:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    'Initialize comboBox1 with sheets in _
    'sheets("Data") column "A"
    Dim LRow As Long
    LRow = LastRow(Sheets("Data"), 1)
    Me.ComboBox1.List = Sheets("Data").Range("A2:A" & _
      LRow).Value2
    UserForm1.Show vbModeless
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim SheetToDelete As Worksheet
    Set SheetToDelete = Sheets(Me.ComboBox1.Text)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim LRow As Long
    LRow = LastRow(Sheets("Data"), 1)
    'delete actual item from comboBox1
    Me.ComboBox1.RemoveItem (Me.ComboBox1.ListIndex)
    Me.ComboBox1.ListIndex = -1
    'copy new comboBox1 list to sheets("Data") column "A"
    Sheets("Data").Range("A1").EntireColumn.ClearContents
    Sheets("Data").Range("A2:A" & LRow - 1) = Me.ComboBox1.List
    'if the sheet we are deleting is selected in
    'Ribbon dropBox "rxlstSheetsList"
    If SheetToDelete.Name = gstrActualNameSheet Then
        'we put the first empty element in dropBox
        glActualIndexSheet = -1
    End If
    'We update the Ribbon dropBox and activate it
    Call RefreshRibbon("Activate")
    'finally we delete the sheet selected in ComboBox1
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    SheetToDelete.Visible = xlSheetVisible
    SheetToDelete.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

In the "ThisWorkbook" module paste this code

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    'At the beginning we hide all sheets in sheets("Data") column "A"
    Sheets("Data").Range("B1") = 1
    Dim LRow As Long
    LRow = LastRow(Sheets("Data"), 1)
    If LRow > 1 Then
        Dim ActualRow As Long
        For ActualRow = 2 To LRow
            If Sheets(Sheets("Data").Range("A" & ActualRow).Text). _
               Visible = xlSheetVisible Then
                Sheets(Sheets("Data").Range("A" & ActualRow).Text). _
                Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
            End If
        Next ActualRow
    End If
End Sub
```

And finally add a standard Module1 with this code

```
Option Explicit
Public grxIRibbonUI As IRibbonUI
Public glActualIndexSheet As Integer
Public gstrActualNameSheet As String

Public Sub rxIRibbonUI_onLoad(ByRef ribbon As IRibbonUI)
    Set grxIRibbonUI = ribbon
End Sub

Public Sub rxlstSheetsList_getSelectedItemIndex(ByRef Control _
  As IRibbonControl, ByRef Index)
    Index = glActualIndexSheet
End Sub

Public Sub rxlstSheetsList_Click(ByRef Control As IRibbonControl, _
  ByVal ID As String, ByVal Index As Integer)
    'first row is empty to hide activesheet
    If glActualIndexSheet + 1 > 1 Then
        gstrActualNameSheet = Sheets("Data").Range("A" & _
          glActualIndexSheet + 1).Text
        Sheets(gstrActualNameSheet).Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
    End If
    glActualIndexSheet = Index
    If Index = 0 Then
        gstrActualNameSheet = ""
    End If
    If glActualIndexSheet + 1 > 1 Then
        gstrActualNameSheet = Sheets("Data").Range("A" & _
          glActualIndexSheet + 1).Text
        Sheets(gstrActualNameSheet).Visible = xlSheetVisible
        Sheets(gstrActualNameSheet).Select
    End If
    On Error Resume Next
    grxIRibbonUI.Invalidate
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub

Public Sub rxshared_getEnabled(ByRef Control As IRibbonControl, _
  ByRef returnedVal)
    returnedVal = Sheets("Data").Range("B1")
    If Sheets("Data").Range("B1") = 1 Then
        returnedVal = True
    Else
        returnedVal = False
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub rxlstSheetsList_getItemCount(ByRef Control As IRibbonControl, _
  ByRef returnedVal)
    returnedVal = LastRow(Sheets("Data"), 1)
End Sub

Public Sub rxlstSheetsList_getItemLabel(ByRef Control As IRibbonControl, _
  ByVal Index As Integer, ByRef returnedVal)
    returnedVal = Sheets("Data").Range("A" & Index + 1)
End Sub

Public Sub rxshared_getLabel(ByRef Control As IRibbonControl, _
  ByRef returnedVal)
    returnedVal = GiveLabel(Control.ID)
    grxIRibbonUI.InvalidateControl Control.ID
End Sub

Public Sub rxbtnEditList_Click(ByRef Control As IRibbonControl)
    Load UserForm1
End Sub

Public Sub RefreshRibbon(ByVal strAction_I As String)
    If strAction_I = "Activate" Then
        Sheets("Data").Range("B1") = 1
    Else
        Sheets("Data").Range("B1") = 0
    End If
    grxIRibbonUI.Invalidate
End Sub

Public Function GiveLabel(ByVal sLabel_I As String) As String
    Select Case sLabel_I
    Case "rxtabMyRibbon"
        GiveLabel = "Sheets"
    Case "rxgrp_SheetsDel"
        GiveLabel = "Sheets to delete"
    Case "rxlstSheetsList"
        GiveLabel = "Sheets list"
    Case "rxbtnEditList"
        GiveLabel = "Delete sheet"
    End Select
End Function

Public Function LastRow(ByRef wsSheet_I As Worksheet, ByVal lColumn_I _
  As Long) As Long
    Dim LRow As Range

    Set LRow = wsSheet_I.Columns(lColumn_I).Find(What:="*", _
                 LookIn:=xlFormulas, lookat:= _
                 xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                 SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)

    If Not LRow Is Nothing Then
        LastRow = LRow.Row
    Else
        LastRow = 0
    End If
End Function
```

The Ribbon XML Code is

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui"
  onLoad="rxIRibbonUI_onLoad">
  <ribbon startFromScratch="false">
    <tabs>
      <tab id="rxtabMyRibbon"
       getLabel="rxshared_getLabel"
       insertBeforeMso="TabHome">
        <group id="rxgrp_SheetsDel" getLabel="rxshared_getLabel">
        <dropDown id="rxlstSheetsList"  
         getSelectedItemIndex="rxlstSheetsList_getSelectedItemIndex"
         getLabel="rxshared_getLabel"
         onAction="rxlstSheetsList_Click"
         getEnabled="rxshared_getEnabled" 
         getItemCount ="rxlstSheetsList_getItemCount"
         getItemLabel="rxlstSheetsList_getItemLabel"
        />
        <button id="rxbtnEditList"
           size="large" 
           imageMso="FilePrepareMenu" 
           getLabel="rxshared_getLabel" 
           onAction="rxbtnEditList_Click" 
           getEnabled="rxshared_getEnabled"
          />
        </group>
      </tab>
    </tabs>
  </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the [InvalidateControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.core.iribbonui.invalidatecontrol?view=office-pia) method of the IRibbonUI interface to get the dropdown control to evaluate its properties.

Be aware, some callbacks can be invoked when you try to open the control.

Comment: Thanks @Eugene but I already tried the Invalidatecontrol method and the result is the same. Something happens but the item deleted from the list remains selected, even if it is no longer in it.

Answer (score 1):

All done. The first element of dropDown is 0 and not -1, in a Combobox you set -1 to empty the list but not in a dropDown. In `Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()` substitute -1 for 0.

```
If SheetToDelete.Name = gstrActualNameSheet Then
    'we put the first empty element in dropBox
    glActualIndexSheet = 0 'Before -1
End If
```

Sorry for the question and I hope it suits someone who has a similar problem